# Extracting key and values in dictionary with in dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, ienumerable

I have a collection of data that look like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<AGString>>> Data = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<AGString>>>();

Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<AGString>> stdData = new Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<AGString>>();
```

later I have to extract this data and place them in another data structure, for example I have made up Data as it follows:

```
stdData.Add(item.ObjectName,item.Contents); // this creates the inner dictionary
Data.Add(collection,stdData); //This creates the final Data dictionary
```

I have tried to extract info by using Data.Key, Data.Keys, but I can not extract the data. Any clue?

Comment: "whatever I do does not work" gives us very little information. We don't know what you've tried, what you were expecting to happen, or what actually happened. Please see http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: I have tried key and value pairs to extract the data from this dictionary in dictionary structure. But, I am not getting the data. I just want to know that what is the general approach in this situation.

Comment: I know of no scenario where I would use nested dictionaries.

Comment: @FabianBigler It is rare to happen, but we have an internal data structure for our proprietary technology, which sometimes runs us in to this rare situation. I am the primary person who has to deal with this unfortunately. But, I have found a nice solution with Linq, which I will post soon.

Comment: @FabianBigler. I used them a lot pre-linq, even post linq Dictionary<String, Dynamic> can be a very powerful description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the elegant way to solve this problem is to use Linq, and you don't need to buy a vowel. 
This structure contains an inner dictionary and outer dictionary. We can access them by Linq as it follows:

```
 var flatKeyValue = from outer in Data
                               from inner in outer.Value
                               select new
                               {
                                   NewKey = outer.Key,
                                   NewVal1 = inner.Key,
                                   NewVal2 = inner.Value
                               };
```

So, now we can access our beloved data by a simple foreach loop:

```
foreach (var item in flatKeyValue)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.NewKey);  // you can try NewVal1, NewVal2 quite simply here
}
```

Comment: Well I looked at it. I like Linq when it gives me a more comprehensible piece of code, far from sure this qualifies, and I remain suspicious of the quest for elegance...

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no clue what you are trying to do but

Given

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<AGString>>> Data = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<AGString>>>();

foreach(string k1 in Data.Keys)
{
   foreach(string k2 in Data[k1].Keys)
   {
      foreach(AGString ag in Data[k1][k2])
      {
         // do something with k1, k2 and ag
      }
   }
}
```